# Taking symbolic variables out of txt file and making a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, export, file-conversion

I have a txt file containing following characters.
theta1 , l1 and others are symbolic variables.( Don't mind about it)

```
 M=[theta1 + (l1^2*m1)/4 + l1^2*m2 (l1*l2*m2*cos(fi1 - fi2))/2 ; 
 (l1*l2*m2*cos(fi1 - fi2))/2 theta2 + (l2^2*m2)/4 ]
```

I need to take it out and make it a symbolic matrix. As you can see txt file is already fine for making matrix but I don't want to copy paste the whole thing to script, I rather want to do it automatically.

```
fid = fopen('a.txt');
MMatrix=textscan(fid,'%s');
fclose(fid);
```

I tried the code above but it turn out to be not useful. What do you think is the way to copy the whole thing and use it for matrix making?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading that as a string or a character array and then possibly resorting to evil ([`eval`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) method, just rename the extension from `txt` to `m` since you already have your arrays defined in the MATLAB way in the text files. Maintain a backup copy of those original txt files if needed.

If it is a single file (`a.txt`), you can rename it manually or with this code to `a.m`:

```
movefile('a.txt', 'a.m');
```

If there are multiple such files in a directory then you can use the following code to change the extension of all such txt files in the current directory:

```
txtfiles = dir('*.txt');   %getting all txt files in the current directory
for num = 1:numel(txtfiles)
    [~, fname] = fileparts(txtfiles(num).name);  %filename (without extension)
    movefile(txtfiles(num).name, [fname,'.m']);  %renaming
end
```

Now you can simply use the name of the respective file in your script to get whatever arrays that file have in it.

Comment: Dear Sardar Usama, as you suggested, I made a script file separately, but frankly speaking I have never used content out of script file from another script file. How can I use it from other script file? To make it clear, I have a.m script file which has M=[...]  ,but I need to use content inside as you code inside a script.

Comment: @Mirroyal If that script file is in your path, you can use its content by simply  writing its name (i.e. `a`) in your script. Or you can also use [`run`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html). Just make sure that your variables do not have a name-conflict with that script file. i.e. you shouldn't have any variable named `a` in your workspace if you want to use the content of  `a.m`

Comment: Dear Sardar Usama, it is good idea to run the script, but it appears that symbolic variables which defined previously are not recognizable in a script file that newly made. How is it possible to read the file as string and assign it to a variable?(using eval as you suggested previously)

Comment: No. I never suggested you that. `eval` is the worst thing to do. It is not possible for the variables to be not recognisable if you initialised/defined them properly.

Comment: they are defined previously inside a script, but this script file that I want to run is different script file. (2 script files, 1 of them has defined variables ,one doesn't have). That is the reason, it encounters error.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many scripts you have unless there are name conflicts and/or variables getting cleared. If you initialise them properly, there will be no problem

Comment: you were right, problem is this, these arrays are created by arrays theta(1) ,theta(2) and etc, but inside script they appear as theta1 which is unrecognizable to matlab.

Comment: You have to fix one of your scripts to maintain the consistency. Using dynamic variables i.e theta1, theta2,... thetaN is a bad idea in general. It may be okay to have them if you have two or three such quantities. Otherwise  you should use theta(1), theta(2),... theta(N)